# Dynamically populate Excel table from cell values from different worksheets with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to populate a `table` in one Excel sheet with information from different `cells` from a different `sheet` in the same `workbook`. Once the table is populated, the user clears the data with a macro (already working) and fill in the `sheet` with new data to be used to add extra rows to the same table, with the same macro used before.

What I want exactly to reproduce is the table in the image below.

[image]

I have tried using the following code without success:

```
Sub saveEvent()

   Dim resultsSht As Worksheet
   Dim lngDestLrow As Long
    
   'Define Worksheets
   Set resultsSht = Sheets("Results")
   Set DestSht = Sheets("ResultsDB")
   
   'Define Destination Sheet Lrow
   lngDestLrow = DestSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   
   'Move Data
   DestSht.Cells(lngDestLrow + 0, "A") = resultsSht.Range("C9") 'Enter the form Field A on the next available row
   'DestSht.Cells(lngDestLrow + 1, "B") = resultsSht.Range("C10") 'Enter the form Field B on the next available row
   'DestSht.Cells(lngDestLrow + 1, "C") = resultsSht.Range("C11") 'Enter the form Field C on the next available row
   'DestSht.Cells(lngDestLrow + 1, "D") = resultsSht.Range("C12") 'Enter the form Field D on the next available row
   'DestSht.Cells(lngDestLrow + 1, "E") = resultsSht.Range("C13") 'Enter the form Field E on the next available row
   'DestSht.Cells(lngDestLrow + 1, "F") = resultsSht.Range("C14") 'Enter the form Field F on the next available row
   'DestSht.Cells(lngDestLrow + 1, "G") = resultsSht.Range("C15") 'Enter the form Field G on the next available row
   'DestSht.Cells(lngDestLrow + 1, "H") = resultsSht.Range("B23") 'Enter the form Field H on the next available row
   'DestSht.Cells(lngDestLrow + 1, "I") = resultsSht.Range("B24")
   'DestSht.Cells(lngDestLrow + 1, "J") = resultsSht.Range("C24")

End Sub
```

Comment: `lngDestLrow` points to the last row with data so you keep overwriting the previously recorded data. The commented section is more promising as you would write in the next (first unused) row. You need to consider another trick: `.End(xlUp).Row` will return 1 when the cell is empty (or empty sheet) or you have data only in 1st row. Or you might specify what you mean by "without success".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub saveEvent()

    Dim wsResult As Worksheet, wsDB As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, i As Long, arr, rw As ListRow
    
    Set wsResult = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
    Set wsDB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ResultsDB")
    
    'array of source ranges on Results
    arr = Array("C9", "C10", "C11", "C12", "C13", "C14", "C15", "B23", "B24", "C24")
    
    'add a new row to the list
    Set rw = wsDB.ListObjects("listNameHere").ListRows.Add()
    
    'fill the row from the source cells
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        rw.Range.Cells(i + 1) = wsResult.Range(arr(i)).Value
    Next i
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Williams, that keeps saving only one row. Probably, worth to mention is that within "ResultsDB" I have a table with the same name to which I need to save the information.

Comment: This code works fine for me - adds a new row each time it runs. I don't know what you mean about a "Table" - do you mean listobject?

Comment: Yes, I mean a listofobject, such that in Excel when you select N rows and columns and click on insert table, that range becomes a table. Let me restart my computer to see why the macro is not working.

Comment: Williams, I made a change in the question. Maybe you can help me out.

Comment: See edits above - it's a little simpler using a listobject.

Comment: Hi Williams, your change only copy the selected range plus some two extra columns one row per click. But I want to copy all String and Sub-string with their corresponding values at once to the table (listObject).

Comment: It worked for me and my code was based on your post as far as copied ranges go.  If that’s not working for you then you’ll need to provide more info